# ASP.NET MVC, register users in a desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an MVC5 project with a template registration, now there has emerged a need to register users in a desktop application. (i.e. a manager uses a desktop application to add info about personal, and while doing that he creates user accounts for the web site). What is a good approach to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must make a desktop app, I would suggest that your desktop app calls to your website to do maintenance via a web service.  This will be much easier to maintain.  You can do this with either WCF or WebApi.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to avoid desktop applications. Its difficult to maintain compared to web projects.

You can use only one database and point your two projects to that database or you can use two projects and use [replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146869.aspx).

Have these three projects in your solution:

- **PublicWeb** (with MVC5)
- **AdminWeb** (with MVC5)
- **DataAccess** (This project will only contain C# methods and will call SQL stored procedures to update tables. I would suggest you to create your database objects (tables and stored procedures) before creating the data access classes and methods.

If you don't want to use DataAccess methods is you can use an Object Relational Mapper software (i.e. NHibernate, Entity Framework or myGrandmasFalseTeeth)

Project should be different if by expected number of visitors are high (like million visitors in a week). In that case you can use NoSql database with Angular JS.

Comment: The problem is - desktop application already exists and it deals with lots and lots of stuff.